# Autogenerated Soap client not parsing the response

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, soap

I added a ServiceReference to one of my projects, not sure if this service is made in .net, when I perform a call to one of the operations, i get an array of objects with 1 element and this element is full of null values, I have checked with fiddler and a response with data is coming in correctly. Do you guys have any idea why this is happening?

SoapResponse structure:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <searchOrderResponse xmlns="http://xml.comcast.com/nationalaccountsportal/services">
         <searchOrderReturn>
            <ns1:searchResult xsi:type="ns1:OrderDetails" xmlns:ns1="http://xml.comcast.com/nationalaccountsportal/types"> <!-- The data -->
            <ns2:searchResult xsi:type="ns2:OrderDetails" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.comcast.com/nationalaccountsportal/types">
```

Autogenerated class definitions:

```
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="searchOrderResponse", WrapperNamespace="http://xml.comcast.com/nationalaccountsportal/services", IsWrapped=true)]
    internal partial class searchOrderResponse {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://xml.comcast.com/nationalaccountsportal/services", Order=0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("searchOrderReturn")]
        public OrderDetails[] searchOrderReturn;

        public searchOrderResponse() {
        }

        public searchOrderResponse(OrderDetails[] searchOrderReturn) {
            this.searchOrderReturn = searchOrderReturn;
        }
    }

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1590.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://xml.comcast.com/nationalaccountsportal/types")]
    public partial class OrderDetails : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
```

searchOrderResponse definition in WSDL:

```
<element name="searchOrderResponse">
        <complexType>
          <sequence>
            <element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="searchOrderReturn" type="tns1:OrderDetails"/>
          </sequence>
        </complexType>
      </element>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a weird implementation of an empty list, i.e. it is a buggy service. A NULL value for the entire collection would work. Hard to say without seeing the WSDL.

Comment: Hi @Namphibian, I added the searchOrderResponse definition from the wsdl, all other definition look standard to me, except for this one, which directly exposes the array of OrderDetails, when on other responses they even create a ResponseType class, I can't make a comparison with other operations within this service because it doesn't have another array type response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update you guys, the issue is that the WSDL is describing the response incorrectly, causing VS to generate incorrect code, it was missing one of the tags or as VS generates 'em, a "ResponseType" so I added:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1590.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://xml.comcast.com/nationalaccountsportal/types")]
public partial class SearchOrderResponseType : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private OrderDetails[] searchResultField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 0)]
    public OrderDetails[] searchResult
    {
        get
        {
            return this.searchResultField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.searchResultField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("searchResult");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null))
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the property is called searchResult, as in the Response structure above, the name of the class can be different, but I kept it as SearchOrderResponseType, since it's how VS would've name it. After this you have to change the return type in the Response class as follows:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="searchOrderResponse", WrapperNamespace="http://xml.comcast.com/nationalaccountsportal/services", IsWrapped=true)]
    internal partial class searchOrderResponse {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://xml.comcast.com/nationalaccountsportal/services", Order=0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("searchOrderReturn")]
        public SearchOrderResponseType searchOrderReturn;

        public searchOrderResponse() {
        }

        public searchOrderResponse(SearchOrderResponseType searchOrderReturn) {
            this.searchOrderReturn = searchOrderReturn;
        }
    }
```

So, basically, it was just one class that was missing, hope this helps